# Want to remove a space char in an API call where the query requires a space

Tags: python, api, urllib2

I am attempting to use www.undata-api.org/ to gather UN Health data. However, if I use their call for getting the available data sets, I get a 404 error:u'Record does not exist'

GET http://api.undata-api.org/{organization}/{database}/database_datasets?app_id=        {app_id}&app_key={app_key}

but the database name is 'WHO Data' -- it has a space in it, and so this call doesn't work. I looked around a bit and saw that people had suggested replacing the space with a '%20' or a +. Neither has worked for me.

I'm using urllib2 in python for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `urllib.quote(YOUR_URL)` to escape the URL for HTTP. Remember to `import urllib`.

Comment: When I try this, I get:
raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
This is happening because I'm using string variables in the url.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the source code?

Comment: I found a work around and the urllib.quote() is now working. Thanks!